# SQL - update each row of a column using while loop

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, sql-update

My original table looks like:

```
week   volume   cost
1        11     null
2        32     null
3        80     null
4        75     null
5        50     null
...      
51       28     null
```

I want to update the cost field by applying a more intelligent rule as follows:

```
if volume < 13, then use a rateA (loose shipment price) 
if volume >= 13 and < 25, then use a rateB (20' container price)
if volume >= 25 and < 45, then use a rateC (40' container price)
```

I want to get the lowest cost by flexibly using above 3 different rates according to the "volume". For instance, in week 4, the "REMAINING VOLUME" initially is 75, I should apply one 40'container cost to load a portion of the volume. Then the "REMAINING VOLUME" is 30, I should apply a 20'container cost to load a portion of the rest. Then the "REMAINING VOLUME" is 5, I should apply the loose shipment price, keep doing in such way until "REMAINING VOLUME" = 0. By doing so it will give me the best combination to minimise the cost per week. Therefore, a while loop needs to be applied to the "REMAINING VOLUME" which can give indication about how to choose the different rates.

the final updated table should look like:

```
   week    volume    cost
    1        11      rateA
    2        32      rateB + rateA
    3        80      rateC + rateB + rateA
    4        75      rateC + rateB + rateA
    5        50      rateC + rateA
    ...      
    51       28      rateB + rateA
```

Comment: A loop is definitely not the best way to handle this. But I can't offer any real suggestion because this is just way too vague. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Jack I think I follow your logic, however there are too many variations with your approach. Logically I would disagree with you on example where the week is 3 - '3        80      rateC + rateB + rateA'  - shouldn't this be rateC + rateC? These are the details needed to be able to assist.

Comment: sorry it's a typo. The max capacity limit for 40' container is in fact 45.

Answer (score 0):

If the cases are fixed and the number of them is small, the following approach works perfectly fine (with SQL Server, anyway; I don't know about other DB's -- see note below) ...

```
UPDATE  #Orders
SET     [Cost] = CASE
            WHEN 0 * 44 + 0 * 24 + 1 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateA'
            WHEN 0 * 44 + 1 * 24 + 0 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateB'
            WHEN 0 * 44 + 1 * 24 + 1 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateB + rateA'
            WHEN 1 * 44 + 0 + 24 + 0 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateC'
            WHEN 1 * 44 + 0 + 24 + 1 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateC + rateA'
            WHEN 1 * 44 + 1 + 24 + 0 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateC + rateB'
            WHEN 1 * 44 + 1 + 24 + 1 * 12 >= [Volume] THEN 'rateC + rateB + rateA'
            ELSE 'too big'
        END
FROM    #Orders
;
```

No looping needed!

Notice the straightforward progression of the cases; you can extend the pattern to include larger weights if you want.

This works with SQL Server because you are guaranteed that the first matching condition is used, so if it matches the third WHEN case it won't try to evaluate the fourth, fifth, etc.  I don't know if this is true for other databases.